# Как сменить расположение миниатюр в вертикальном расположении слайдера lightSlider?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

lightSlider при переключении в вертикальный режим выводит панель миниатюр с правой стороны, а как переместить их влево?Какой стиль или набор стилей в css-файле за это отвечает?
Код моих настроек слайдера:

```
$("#vertical").lightSlider({
    gallery:true,
    adaptiveHeight:true,
    item:1,
    vertical:true,
    verticalHeight:1100,
    vThumbWidth:65,
    thumbItem:10,
    thumbMargin:2,
    slideMargin:3
});
```

Answer (score 0):

В сss можно так выравнивать по левому краю

```css
.slider {
    display: flex,
    justify-content: flex-start;
{
```

```html
<div class="slider"> Слайдер </div>
```